# Can I find a solution for this query ,please?

Tags: sql-server

SQL query: for each project, find the project number, project name and the total number of hours that employees worked for this project and order the results by the total work hours.

Consider this example data:
[OP should edit this to make sure it reflects their actual circumstance]

```
DECLARE @Project TABLE (PNo INT IDENTITY, PName NVARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @WorksFor TABLE (WNo INT IDENTITY, WName NVARCHAR(50), Hours INT, PNo INT)

INSERT INTO @Project (Pname) VALUES
('SQL Refectoring'),('Unit Testing')

INSERT INTO @WorksFor (WName, Hours, PNO) VALUES
('Joe', 1, 1),('Joe', 5, 1),('Jim', 3, 1),('Bob', 2, 1),
('Joe', 1, 2),('Joe', 3, 2),('Joe', 7, 2),('Joe', 1, 2)
```

What is wrong with my query? Why does this SQL code not work ?

```
select Pname, Pnumber,
        (select sum(Hours) from Worksfor group by (Pno)) as total_hours
    from 
        Project P, Worksfor w
    where 
        p.Pnumber = w.Pno
    order by 
        w.Hours
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: The subquery for `total_hours` appears to return multiple rows, which is not allowed.

Comment: `(select sum(Hours) from Worksfor where p.Pnumber = Worksfor .Pno group by (Pno)) as total_hours` Never saw your kind of join but I'm pretty sure inside subquery you need to set the link.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

using some example data:

```
DECLARE @Project TABLE (PNo INT IDENTITY, PName NVARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @WorksFor TABLE (WNo INT IDENTITY, WName NVARCHAR(50), Hours INT, PNo INT)

INSERT INTO @Project (Pname) VALUES
('SQL Refectoring'),('Unit Testing')

INSERT INTO @WorksFor (WName, Hours, PNO) VALUES
('Joe', 1, 1),('Joe', 5, 1),('Jim', 3, 1),('Bob', 2, 1),
('Joe', 1, 2),('Joe', 3, 2),('Joe', 7, 2),('Joe', 1, 2)
```

We can join these two tables together (properly, as the method you are trying to use is depreciated as mentioned in the comments).

```
SELECT PName, p.PNo, SUM(wf.Hours) AS hours
  FROM @Project p
    INNER JOIN @WorksFor wf
      ON p.PNo = wf.PNo
 GROUP BY PName, p.Pno
```

Here we are joining the Project table to the Works for table on the PNo column. Then we aggregate the hours up by PNo and PName to sum the hours:

```
PName           PNo hours
-------------------------
SQL Refectoring 1   11
Unit Testing    2   12
```

Things to consider:

- Table and columns names should be descriptive, there is little reason to abbreviate them into gibberish any longer. 'ThisIsTheProjectNameAsDefinedByProjectManagement' is obviously excessive but 'PMOOfficeProjectName' reasonable. Table names should also, usually, be pluralized as they represent one or many entities.
- Alias' should always be defined and used when referring columns. This makes code easier to read and prevents ambiguity.